# Logistic Regression PMML won't Produce Probabilities

Tags: python, r, data-science, pmml, knime

As part of a machine-learning deployment project, I built a proof-of-concept where I created two simple logistic regression models for a binary classification task using R's `glm` function and python's `scikit-learn`. Afterwards, I converted those trained simple models to `PMML`s using the `pmml` function in R, and the `from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline` function in Python.

Next, I opened a very simple workflow in KNIME to see if I can put those two `PMML`s into action. Basically the goal of this proof-of-concept is to test if IT can score new data using the `PMML`s that I simply hand over to them. This exercise must produce probabilities, just like the original logistic regressions would.

In KNIME, I read a test data of only 4 rows using `CSV Reader` node, read the `PMML` using the `PMML Reader` node, and finally get that model to score that test data using `PMML Predictor` node. The problem is that the predictions are not final probabilities that I want, but one step before that (sum of coefficients times independent variable values, called XBETA I guess?). Please see the workflow and predictions in the picture below:

[image: KNIME output]

To get to the final probabilities, one needs to run these numbers through the sigmoid function. So basically for the first record, instead of `2.654`, I need `1/(1+exp(-2.654)) = 0.93`. I am sure the `PMML` file contains the required information to enable KNIME (**or any other similar platform**) to perform this sigmoid operation for me, but I failed to find it. That is where I desperately need help.

I looked into [regression](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/Regression.html) and [general regression](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/GeneralRegression.html#xsdType_LINK-FUNCTION) `PMML` documentations, and my PMMLs look just fine, but I can't figure out why I am unable to get those probabilities.

Any help is highly appreciated!

#### Attachment 1 - Here is my test data:

```
age credit  payfreq gmi
25  550 4   1500
27  650 4   3400
35  600 2   3200
40  680 2   4000
```

#### Attachment 2 - Here is my R-generated PMML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PMML version="4.2" xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2 http://www.dmg.org/v4-2/pmml-4-2.xsd">
 <Header copyright="Copyright (c) 2018 fakici" description="Generalized Linear Regression Model">
  <Extension name="user" value="fakici" extender="Rattle/PMML"/>
  <Application name="Rattle/PMML" version="1.4"/>
  <Timestamp>2018-10-30 17:36:39</Timestamp>
 </Header>
 <DataDictionary numberOfFields="5">
  <DataField name="bad" optype="categorical" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="age" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="credit" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="payfreq" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="gmi" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
 </DataDictionary>
 <GeneralRegressionModel modelName="General_Regression_Model" modelType="generalLinear" functionName="regression" algorithmName="glm" distribution="binomial" linkFunction="logit" targetReferenceCategory="1">
  <MiningSchema>
   <MiningField name="bad" usageType="predicted" invalidValueTreatment="returnInvalid"/>
   <MiningField name="age" usageType="active" invalidValueTreatment="returnInvalid"/>
   <MiningField name="credit" usageType="active" invalidValueTreatment="returnInvalid"/>
   <MiningField name="payfreq" usageType="active" invalidValueTreatment="returnInvalid"/>
   <MiningField name="gmi" usageType="active" invalidValueTreatment="returnInvalid"/>
  </MiningSchema>
  <Output>
   <OutputField name="Predicted_bad" feature="predictedValue"/>
  </Output>
  <ParameterList>
   <Parameter name="p0" label="(Intercept)"/>
   <Parameter name="p1" label="age"/>
   <Parameter name="p2" label="credit"/>
   <Parameter name="p3" label="payfreq"/>
   <Parameter name="p4" label="gmi"/>
  </ParameterList>
  <FactorList/>
  <CovariateList>
   <Predictor name="age"/>
   <Predictor name="credit"/>
   <Predictor name="payfreq"/>
   <Predictor name="gmi"/>
  </CovariateList>
  <PPMatrix>
   <PPCell value="1" predictorName="age" parameterName="p1"/>
   <PPCell value="1" predictorName="credit" parameterName="p2"/>
   <PPCell value="1" predictorName="payfreq" parameterName="p3"/>
   <PPCell value="1" predictorName="gmi" parameterName="p4"/>
  </PPMatrix>
  <ParamMatrix>
   <PCell parameterName="p0" df="1" beta="14.4782176066955"/>
   <PCell parameterName="p1" df="1" beta="-0.16633241754673"/>
   <PCell parameterName="p2" df="1" beta="-0.0125492006930571"/>
   <PCell parameterName="p3" df="1" beta="0.422786551151072"/>
   <PCell parameterName="p4" df="1" beta="-0.0005500245399861"/>
  </ParamMatrix>
 </GeneralRegressionModel>
</PMML>
```

#### Attachment 3 - Here is my Python-generated PMML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PMML xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2" xmlns:data="http://jpmml.org/jpmml-model/InlineTable" version="4.2">
    <Header>
        <Application name="JPMML-SkLearn" version="1.5.8"/>
        <Timestamp>2018-10-30T22:10:32Z</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <MiningBuildTask>
        <Extension>PMMLPipeline(steps=[('mapper', DataFrameMapper(default=False, df_out=False,
        features=[(['age', 'credit', 'payfreq', 'gmi'], [ContinuousDomain(high_value=None, invalid_value_replacement=None,
         invalid_value_treatment='return_invalid', low_value=None,
         missing_value_replacement=None, missing_value_treatment='as_is',
         missing_values=None, outlier_treatment='as_is', with_data=True,
         with_statistics=True), Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)])],
        input_df=False, sparse=False)),
       ('classifier', LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False))])</Extension>
    </MiningBuildTask>
    <DataDictionary>
        <DataField name="bad" optype="categorical" dataType="double">
            <Value value="0"/>
            <Value value="1"/>
        </DataField>
        <DataField name="age" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="20.0" rightMargin="50.0"/>
        </DataField>
        <DataField name="credit" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="501.0" rightMargin="699.0"/>
        </DataField>
        <DataField name="payfreq" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="2.0" rightMargin="4.0"/>
        </DataField>
        <DataField name="gmi" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
            <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="1012.0" rightMargin="4197.0"/>
        </DataField>
    </DataDictionary>
    <RegressionModel functionName="classification" normalizationMethod="softmax" algorithmName="glm" targetFieldName="bad">
        <MiningSchema>
            <MiningField name="bad" usageType="target"/>
            <MiningField name="age" missingValueReplacement="35.05" missingValueTreatment="asMean"/>
            <MiningField name="credit" missingValueReplacement="622.28" missingValueTreatment="asMean"/>
            <MiningField name="payfreq" missingValueReplacement="2.74" missingValueTreatment="asMean"/>
            <MiningField name="gmi" missingValueReplacement="3119.4" missingValueTreatment="asMean"/>
        </MiningSchema>
        <Output>
            <OutputField name="probability(0)" optype="categorical" dataType="double" feature="probability" value="0"/>
            <OutputField name="probability(1)" optype="categorical" dataType="double" feature="probability" value="1"/>
        </Output>
        <ModelStats>
            <UnivariateStats field="age">
                <Counts totalFreq="100.0" missingFreq="0.0" invalidFreq="0.0"/>
                <NumericInfo minimum="20.0" maximum="50.0" mean="35.05" standardDeviation="9.365228240678386" median="40.5" interQuartileRange="18.0"/>
            </UnivariateStats>
            <UnivariateStats field="credit">
                <Counts totalFreq="100.0" missingFreq="0.0" invalidFreq="0.0"/>
                <NumericInfo minimum="501.0" maximum="699.0" mean="622.28" standardDeviation="76.1444784603585" median="662.0" interQuartileRange="150.5"/>
            </UnivariateStats>
            <UnivariateStats field="payfreq">
                <Counts totalFreq="100.0" missingFreq="0.0" invalidFreq="0.0"/>
                <NumericInfo minimum="2.0" maximum="4.0" mean="2.74" standardDeviation="0.9656086163658655" median="2.0" interQuartileRange="2.0"/>
            </UnivariateStats>
            <UnivariateStats field="gmi">
                <Counts totalFreq="100.0" missingFreq="0.0" invalidFreq="0.0"/>
                <NumericInfo minimum="1012.0" maximum="4197.0" mean="3119.4" standardDeviation="1282.4386379082625" median="4028.5" interQuartileRange="2944.0"/>
            </UnivariateStats>
        </ModelStats>
        <RegressionTable targetCategory="1" intercept="0.9994024132088255">
            <NumericPredictor name="age" coefficient="-0.1252021965856186"/>
            <NumericPredictor name="credit" coefficient="-8.682780007730786E-4"/>
            <NumericPredictor name="payfreq" coefficient="1.2605378393614861"/>
            <NumericPredictor name="gmi" coefficient="1.4681704138387003E-4"/>
        </RegressionTable>
        <RegressionTable targetCategory="0" intercept="0.0"/>
    </RegressionModel>
</PMML>
```

Comment: I think the PMML Predictor node uses JPMML, and it is possible their implementation is incomplete. Could you check the [Logistic Regression Predictor node](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.mine.regression.logistic.predictor.LogisticRegressionPredictorNodeFactory)? That should output probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @GáborBakos but that node creates even harder problems, like "NullPointerException", "This node does not support numerical targets" etc.

Comment: The "PMML Predictor" node should be KNIME's own implementaion. Please consider using a "JPMML classifier" node (probabilities are related classification models), which used to be available in KNIME Labs.

Answer (score 2):

One solution floating around is to use the Math Formula node to apply the sigmoid function on the output of the PMML Predictor. Have you tried that?